# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build register api. Here i am stuck with the problem and hoping you guys will address my mistake and will lead me to right way. Anyway thanks in advance. Hoping for your soon response. Thank you .

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Create and return a new user"""
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UserRegisterManager(BaseUserManager):
    """ Helps django work with our custom user model """

    def createUser(self, email, name, password=None):
        """ Creates a new user profile object """

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address.")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)  # set_password helps to convert str into hash
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        """ Creates and saves a new superuser with given details. """

        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class UserRegister(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """ Represents a 'user register' inside our system """
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # user is currently active or not
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserRegisterManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        """ Used to get user fullname """

        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """ Used to get user short name """

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """ Django uses this when it need to convert the object to a string """

        return self.email
```

this is my model

**views.py**

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

from .serializers import UserSerializer
from . import permissions
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited. """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    # permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateProfile,)
```

**setting.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'register.UserRegister'
```

this helps to switch to costume user.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import UserRegister

admin.site.register(UserRegister)
```

And this is how i register my model

**Error**

[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOYiI.png)

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/

Django Version: 2.1.5
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'register',
 'corsheaders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py" in rendered_content
  72.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in render
  733.         context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in get_context
  663.         raw_data_post_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'POST', request)

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in get_raw_data_form
  574.                 data = serializer.data.copy()

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  563.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  266.                 self._data = self.get_initial()

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in get_initial
  413.             for field in self.fields.values()

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in fields
  363.             for key, value in self.get_fields().items():

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in get_fields
  1024.         info = model_meta.get_field_info(model)

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\model_meta.py" in get_field_info
  39.     forward_relations = _get_forward_relationships(opts)

File "C:\Users\Pashupati Pariyar\Desktop\Django + Angular\Backend\api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\model_meta.py" in _get_forward_relationships
  96.                 not field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/register/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Please post the complete error traceback.

Comment: Arpit Svt i just did

Comment: Why is your UserSerializer using model User rather than UserRegister?

Comment: because of this "from django.contrib.auth.models import User"

Comment: Daniel Roseman you were right. Thanks for the help and you help me again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Always use that to access the user model instead of this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

to account for custom user models.